# How can I enforce 'use strict' in Backbone codebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Think when you have many views, models, collections and a router and you use `Require.js`

Is there a better way to enforce `use strict` in the entire codebase by specifying it as a configuration or setting, rather than doing this?

[image]

Comment: No, you need to do it separately for each script.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Post the text and [format it as code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: While not "configuration", you should be able to do it as a deployment/build step (if you have one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare 'use strict' inside a function or outside of it, but either way it only applies to the file you declare it in; there is no "global use strict".

Personally I just configure my IDE (Eclipse) to write out the 'use strict' for me in my new file template, but if you don't like having to do that you could always (as WiredPrairie suggested) do it during some form of "compilation" step.